# Multiple connected/dependent sliders with Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, slider, dijit.form

I am trying to create some sliders, which are interconnected. All sliders should always give a sum of 100. So, if Slider 1 = 50, Slider 2 and 3 should be set to 25 automatically.

The code works so far with some limitations: I cannot manipulate the sliders live (intermediateChange: true) and the sliders do not move any more, when one of them reached 100 and so the residuum got 0.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    require(["dijit/form/HorizontalSlider"], function(HorizontalSlider) {
        var slider1 = new HorizontalSlider({
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100,
            value: 10,
            intermediateChanges: false,
            onChange: function() {
                console.log("Slider 1: " + slider1.get('value'));
                var residue = slider2.get('value') + slider3.get('value')
                slider2.set('value', (slider2.get('value') / residue) * (100 - slider1.get('value')));
                slider3.set('value', (slider3.get('value') / residue) * (100 - slider1.get('value')));
            }
        }, "slider1");

        var slider2 = new HorizontalSlider({
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100,
            value: 45,
            intermediateChanges: false,
            onChange: function() {
                console.log("Slider 2: " + slider2.get('value'));
                var residue = slider1.get('value') + slider3.get('value')
                slider1.set('value', (slider1.get('value') / residue) * (100 - slider2.get('value')));
                slider3.set('value', (slider3.get('value') / residue) * (100 - slider2.get('value')));
            }
        }, "slider2");

        var slider3 = new HorizontalSlider({
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100,
            value: 45,
            intermediateChanges: false,
            onChange: function() {
                console.log("Slider 3: " + slider3.get('value'));
                var residue = slider1.get('value') + slider2.get('value')
                slider1.set('value', (slider1.get('value') / residue) * (100 - slider3.get('value')));
                slider2.set('value', (slider2.get('value') / residue) * (100 - slider3.get('value')));
            }
        }, "slider3");

        slider1.startup();
        slider2.startup();
        slider3.startup();
    });
</script>
```

How can I achieve the sliders keep connected, even if one was put to maximum?
Is there a smarter solution? In this way the code gets longer with every additional slider...

Comment: I think you need to use **publish/subscribe** module of dojo which will  help you to initiate automatic slider manipulation. The logic would be something like this. A change in any one of the slider will publish the value along with the name of the slider that caused the change. The other sliders that have subscribed will get the values and change its own value depending upon the business logic desired by you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [dojo/aspect] package.http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/aspect.html

for example:

```
//example object
var original = {
        someMethod: function(arg1, arg2) {
            console.warn("original.someMethod called: ", arg1, arg2);
            return "Hello " + arg1 + " " + arg2;
        }
    };
//executed after "somemthod"
aspect.after(original, "someMethod", function(arg1, arg2) {
        console.warn("After method called with arguments: ", arg1, arg2);
    }, true);

//executed before "someMethod"
    aspect.before(original, "someMethod", function(arg1, arg2) {
        console.warn("aspect.before: ", arg1, arg2);
    });

// calling "someMethod" shall trigger aspect before and after ,  
    original.someMethod("micro", "soft");
```

you can make aspect/after to the first slider onChange method and make changes to the second and third slider inside the aspect/after method

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice example of connected sliders with jQuery UI: [http://jsfiddle.net/redsunsoft/caPAb/2/][1]

And I need exactly the same functionality in Dojo. So I am trying to translate it, but I do not understand, how to do some basic things with Dojo.

Here is my code so far, with a few comments/questions:

```
<script>
    require(["dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/query", "dijit/form/HorizontalSlider", "dojo/NodeList-manipulate", "dojo/NodeList-traverse"], function(domConstruct, query, HorizontalSlider) {
        var sliders = query("#sliders .slider");
        var availableTotal = 100;

        sliders.forEach(function(node) {
            var init_value = parseInt(query(node).text());

            query(node).siblings(".value").text(init_value);

            domConstruct.empty(node);

            var slider = new HorizontalSlider({ // Is it ok to create a new variable with the same name for every slider?
                value: init_value,
                minimum: 0,
                maximum: availableTotal,
                discreteValues: 101,
                intermediateChanges: true,
                showButtons: false,
                onChange: function(value) {
                    query(node).siblings(".value").text(Math.round(value)); // Does not work, though it works outside the onChange function

                    var total = 0;

                    sliders.forEach(function() { // How can I select all sliders, except the current one (jQuery: "not(this)")
                        total += query(node).siblings(".slider").get("value"); // How can I get the values of the sliders?
                    });

                    total += value; // Is "value" the actual value of the slider, that is moved?

                    var delta = availableTotal - total;

                    sliders.forEach(function() {
                        var t = query(node);
                        var value = t.siblings(".slider").get("value");

                        var new_value = value + (delta/2);

                        if (new_value < 0 || value == 100) 
                            new_value = 0;
                        if (new_value > 100) 
                            new_value = 100;

                        t.siblings(".value").text(Math.round(new_value));
                        t.siblings(".slider").set("value", new_value); // How can I set the values of the sliders?
                    });
                }
            }, node);

            slider.startup(); // Where to startup the sliders?
        });
    });
</script>
```